# Is it possible to make unified insert function

Tags: node.js, node-mysql

So I have this piece of code, but I can't know how many arguments the function will take before I actually use it

```
function insert(...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        //                               ↓↓↓ - here is the problem
        db.query('INSERT INTO `?` VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?);', args, (err, rows) => {
            return err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
```

Is it possible to modify this function so it will allow me to insert as many arguments as I need?

Comment: Writing your own query generator can be tedious and error prone. Instead, consider using an existing generator, knex.js would be just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would probably be, using `args.length` to generate the appropriate number of `?`

```
function insert(...args) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let qm = Array(args.length-1).fill('?', 0).join(',');
        let query = `INSERT INTO \`?\` VALUES(${qm});`
        db.query(query, args, (err, rows) => {
            return err ? reject(err) : resolve(rows);
        });
    });
}
```

But you should probably stick to Wiktor Zychla's suggestion, and don't try to write your own query generator. Especially -- no offense -- if you need to ask questions on that level ...

Comment: Values still end up from args into SQL statement

Comment: @AliHabibzadeh Yes, but they are correctly escaped by the mysql module, which prevents sql injection. That's the whole point of using prepared statements